# emacs-parallel not found

Tags: osx

I am trying to run tests for a project called omnisharp-emacs. When I do so the following warning appears:

```
Warning: Lisp directory `/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.5/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/emacs-parallel': No such file or directory
```

Emacs was installed on MacOsX using brew, and is up to date. I have not idea what is that emacs-parallel. Haven't found any information, on searches, and doesn't appear on elpa, melpa, melpa stable, or marmalade.

Could anybody explain me what it is (or point to where it is explained), and how to install it?

Comment: Try searching on, say, google.com

Comment: I use DuckDuckGo. Is the first time that I have a result not appearing in there (and now I can see that appears as the first result on google)

Comment: Funnily, the top hit on DuckDuckGo for "emacs-parallel" now is... your question here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the package assumes that you have the external package `emacs-parallel` installed. You can get it from [its GitHUB page](https://github.com/daimrod/emacs-parallel).